# get an error while insert data to database

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I make usual registration form, but it is get an error **'

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

After that, I run a query

```
var_dump($this->conn->errorInfo());
```

and the result was **

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

Here it is my code from class.user.php file:

```
 public function register
($nama,$noktp,$alamat,$kota,$jeniskelamin,$tempatlahir,$tanggallahir,$nomorhp,
 $email,$namainstansi,$pimpinaninstansi,$kotainstansi,$jnsinstansi,$nomortelepon,$emailinstansi)
{
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name,user_email) 
                                                   VALUES(:nama,:user_email)");

        $stmt->bindparam(':name', $nama,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':user_email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lastInsertID = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_user
                                      (id_pengguna,no_ktp,alamat,kota,jenis_kelamin,tempat_lahir,tanggal_lahir,nomor_hp)
                                      VALUES(:idpengguna,:noktp,:alamat,:kota,:jk,:tempatlahir,:tanggallahir,:nomorhp)");
        $stmt->bindparam(':idpengguna', $lastInsertID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':noktp', $noktp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':alamat', $alamat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':kota', $kota, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':jk', $jeniskelamin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':tempatlahir', $tempatlahir, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':tanggallahir', $tanggallahir, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':nomorhp', $nomorhp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_instansi
                                      (id_pengguna,nama_instansi,pimpinan,kota,jenis_instansi,nomor_telepon,email_instansi)
                                      VALUES(:idpengguna,:namainstansi,:pimpinan,:kota,:jenisinstansi,:nomortelepon,:emailinstansi)");
        $stmt->bindparam(':idpengguna', $lastInsertID,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':namainstansi', $namainstansi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':pimpinan', $pimpinaninstansi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':kota', $kotainstansi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':jenisinstansi', $jnsinstansi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':nomortelepon', $nomortelepon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(':emailinstansi', $emailinstansi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();


        $this->conn->commit();

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->conn->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage();
       var_dump($this->conn->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Codes on register.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $noktp = $_POST['ktp'];
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $kota = $_POST['kota'];
    $jk = $_POST['jk'];
    $tempatlahir = $_POST['tempat'];
    $tanggallahir = $_POST['tgl'];
    $nomorhp = $_POST['hp'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $namainstansi = $_POST['namains'];
    $pimpinanins = $_POST['pimins'];
    $kotains = $_POST['kotains'];
    $jenisins = $_POST['jins'];
    $nomortlp = $_POST['notel'];
    $emailins = $_POST['emailins'];


    try{
      $user_register->register($nama,$noktp,$alamat,$kota,$jk,$tempatlahir,$tanggallahir,
            $nomorhp,$email,$namainstansi,$pimpinanins,$kotains,$jenisins,$nomortlp,$emailins);


    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

And here it is the form:

```
<form id="msform" action="registrasi.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- progressbar -->


  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Identitas Pengguna</li>
    <li>Identitas Instansi</li>
    <li>Dokumen Pendukung</li>
      <li>Konfirmasi Hasil</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->

  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Identitas Pengguna</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Lengkapi Identitas Pribadi Anda</h3>
      <table border="0">
          <tr style="width: 100%">
              <td class="judul-tabel">Nama</td>
              <td style="width: 800px"><input name="nama" placeholder="Masukkan Nama" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">No KTP</td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="17" name="ktp" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor KTP" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel" style="vertical-align: middle">Alamat</td>
              <td><textarea name="alamat" placeholder="Masukkan Alamat" required></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Kota</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="kota" placeholder="Masukkan Kota" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Jenis Kelamin</td>
              <td class="isi-tabel">
                  <input type="radio" name="jk" value="Laki-laki"
                         style="width: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px;" required>Laki-laki
                  <input type="radio" name="jk" value="Perempuan"
                         style="width: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px;" required>Perempuan
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Tempat Lahir</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tempat" placeholder="Masukkan Tempat Lahir" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Tanggal Lahir</td>
              <td><input type="date" name="tgl" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Nomor Hp</td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="12" name="hp" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor Hp" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Email</td>
              <td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Masukkan Email" required></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" name="stepone" id="stepone" class="next action-button" value="Selanjutnya" />

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Identitas Instansi</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Lanjutkan dengan Pengisian Data Kantor Anda</h3>
      <table border="0">
          <tr style="width: 100%">
              <td class="judul-tabel">Nama Instansi</td>
              <td style="width: 900px"><input type="text" name="namains" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Pimpinan Instansi</td>
              <td style="width: 800px"><input type="text" name="pimins" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Pimpinan Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Kota Instansi</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="kotains" placeholder="Masukkan Kota Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Jenis Instansi</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="jins" placeholder="Masukkan Jenis Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Nomor Telepon</td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="12" name="notel" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor Telepon Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="judul-tabel">Email Instansi</td>
              <td><input type="email" name="emailins" placeholder="Masukkan Email Instansi" required></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Sebelumnya" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daftar">
  </fieldset>



    <?php




    ?>
</form>
```

I have checked if the parameters and variables have appropriate, the parameters is 15, so do the variables. But it still doesn't work. What's wrong with my codes, btw? I hope I can find the answer here, sorry for my broken english.

Comment: Why is your parameter named `nama` in the query, but you assign stuff to the parameter `name`? Or does the error occur with the larger query?

Comment: Oh my bad. I should make the both of parameter have the same name. I make a typo. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My code has worked anyway

Comment: So, is the problem solved now?

Comment: Yes, It is solved.